# Java granting permission from code

Tags: java, permissions, policy

I am currently setting a policy file using:

```
policyURL =cl.getResource("res/policy/abc.policy");
System.out.println(policyURL.toString());
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", policyURL.toString());
```

The problem is that the file interferes with other running applications.

Is it possible to grant a permission from code and remove it when the application stops? I don't want to modify the java.policy from ProgramFiles.

Comment: From Oracle Documentation: It is also possible to specify an additional or a different policy file when invoking execution of an application. This can be done via the "-Djava.security.policy" command line argument, which sets the value of the java.security.policy property. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html

Comment: I'm executing from eclipse, how would I do that?

Comment: Setting environment arguments is easy in eclipse: Select Run > Run Configurations, double click on Java Application, select the Arguments tab and place the command line argument in the VM arguments text area. That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you set it on the JVM through the following properties:

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=res/policy/abc.policy
```

I would suspect this would not impact other running applications.